# Unable to compile project using MIO - use of unstable library feature 'udp_extras'

Tags: rust

I am trying to reproduce a TCP client/server chat from an article. I cannot compile the skeleton for the server which uses the `mio` crate. Here is my code:

```
extern crate mio;
use mio::*;

struct WebSocketServer;

impl Handler for WebSocketServer {
    type Timeout = usize;
    type Message = ();
}

fn main() {
    let mut event_loop = EventLoop::new().unwrap();
    let mut handler = WebSocketServer;
    event_loop.run(&mut handler).unwrap();
}
```

And here is error message which is absolutely unclear for me:

```
C:\Users\ZZZ\.cargo\git\checkouts\mio-75006fe295376f74\master\src\sys\windows\udp.rs:177:44: 177:61 error: use of unstab
le library feature 'udp_extras': available through the `net2` crate on crates.io
C:\Users\ZZZ\.cargo\git\checkouts\mio-75006fe295376f74\master\src\sys\windows\udp.rs:177         try!(self.inner().socke
t.socket()).set_broadcast(on)
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `mio`.
```

And here is  `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "rust-chat"
version = "0.2.0"
authors = ["Alex <zzz@yyy.com>"]

[dependencies.mio]
git = "https://github.com/carllerche/mio"
```

I tried to add `net2` to section `dependencies` explicitly but that still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Windows support of `mio` (or `rust`) still not very good. So this code, which does not compiled with `rustc 1.3-stable` was compiled successfully with `rusts 1.5-nightly`.